# Apple SE cell phone goes into voice control mode when I unpause it

Tags: iphone, headphones

I have an iPhone SE with iOS 12.1.4. which I use primarily as a mp3 player.
I am using the apple earpods (wired in ear headphones with remote).

I can pause the audio no problem by a single short tap on the remote button on the earpod.

The issue is when I single short press again, to take the SE out of pause mode and into play mode, the SE goes into Voice Control Mode instead instead of play mode.

I can put it in and out of pause mode every time if I unpause soon enough. However if I leave it in pause mode for a while, it will go into voice control mode when I try to unpause it.

If it comes up in voice control mode I can get it out of that state by repeatedly pressing the Home button or if that doesn't work, a restart will fix it.

I don't know if it matters, but my SE has a sim card installed however I use the SE in airplane mode with wifi and bluetooth only enabled (no cell network)

I have:

- updated to the latest o.s.
- bought new headphones
- tried new podcast player app.
- set SE to factory restore

  Any suggestions?

edit

I have replaced the headphone jack. It did not fix the problem.

Is their a way to disable voice control entirely?

Comment: ...why not take out the sim card?

Comment: It's an issue I've experienced occasionally with my iPhone 6s, iOS 10.3.3. The problem is the unpause button on the music controlling device

Comment: It's a bit slow and think that it's being held down for a little bit

Comment: So... Headphone jack I guess? Being that you bought new headphones

Comment: Maybe clean your headphone jack? Idk