# How to stop headphones activating Voice Control (even though it’s disabled) when unpausing music?

Tags: iphone, ios, headphones

I use a pair of in-ear, noise-cancelling Sennheiser headphones with my iPhone 6S. I don’t know exactly which model they are, but something like [the CX 5.00i](https://www.sennheiser.com/earphones-mic-cx-5-00) isn’t far off. The headphones have a little inline remote control which I use a lot to pause and play songs.

The trouble is that about half the time I do so – particularly if a song has been paused for more than about 30 seconds, and particularly if I’m moving rather than standing still – hitting the button on the remote doesn’t restart the music like it’s supposed to, but instead activates Voice Control (with that VERY loud ‘dun-dun’ sound rendering me half deaf every time).

I have Voice Control disabled as [described in the answer to this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/253788/disabling-voice-control-or-at-least-muting-it-ios-10), and long-clicking the home button on the actual phone doesn’t activate it. I also have Siri completely disabled.

It seems to be a fairly common issue that Voice Control randomly activates itself while music is playing, but in my case, of course, music **isn’t** playing when this happens. I’ve only been able to find a few other cases where unpausing is specifically mentioned: there’s a [post in a MacRumors thread](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/how-to-listen-to-music-on-earphones-without-voice-control-interfering.2038404/page-2#post-26571267) (no answer in the thread) and a [previous question here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/352355/apple-se-cell-phone-goes-into-voice-control-mode-when-i-unpause-it) (which doesn’t mention whether Voice Control has been disabled and also has no answers).

I’ve tried changing to the standard Apple headphones – no change. Unpausing using the headphone remote still activates Voice Control if I wait more than 30 or so seconds or neglect to stand completely still.

Why/how does this happen? How do my headphones manage to activate Voice Control when it is otherwise disabled as much as it can be? And more importantly, is there a way to **stop it**?

Comment: :( same here, no answers.